# why does String reference variable stores string and not an address in java?

Tags: java

```
public class ARRAYS {
    public static void main ( String[] args){

    String s = new String("Hello");
    System.out.println(s);

    char[] abc = new char[5];
    abs[0] = 'a';
    abs[1] = 'b';
    abs[2] = 'c';
    abs[3] = 'd';
    abs[4] = 'e';
    System.out.println(abc);

    doggy d = new doggy();
    System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

here there are 3 objects, char array object ( referred by abc ), string object ( referred by s) and doggy object ( referred by d )
as abc, d and s are reference variables, how come d stores address but abc and s store contents of array?

Comment: D doesn't really stores the address, it's just that Doggy probably doesn't override the toString() method, so by default the address is printed. If you override the method toString() to return a String representing the values of your Doggy, the output would be different.

Comment: all variables reference address of objects (either string or arrays or even doggy). You need to implement the toString() method in your objects as Kevin mentions above in all your objects in order to print them.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `System.out.println(object);` what you'll actually see printed is the value of `object.toString()` (which returns a `String` which is why `String` also must be represented by their content).

So it is because the `String` object overrides the default `toString()` method.
And that `doggy` and `arrays` don't.